# How to change the url of a one page slider website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a one page slider where i use different section for different contents. I am targeting `id` to make the slider work. In that case all I need to change my address bar `url` with the name of my contents `id` but nor with `hash`. For instance it have to be like `www.mywebsite.com/home` where it should target to my home section.

I gave a scratch to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64kk9yck/) for more reference

```
<div id="body">
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="home" id="home">Home Content</div>
<div class="about" id="about">About Content</div>

<a href="#body" class="top">Top</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have I understood you correct that you want to change the contents of your addressbar onclick?

Comment: yes i want to change my addressbar url with the id of my contents on click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 and pushState for that

Like this

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

For for info see [Manipulating_the_browser_history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: I tried this and with no success can you update my fiddle what i am making i know i cannot see results on fiddle though i can try on ma local using the fiddle.

Comment: Ah sry. Should have said that it won't work on jsfiddle. Try implement it for real instead. Or look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/

Comment: Im using href to navigate to my contents so cant remove `#` need to remove it dynamically

Comment: [This](https://ad8657f1b83175540fff14c664da18e656e01250.googledrive.com/host/0B6jEeghp1bpxX0NyOXI5Sjh3eHM) is the link to my website i don't want the hast to appear in the url

Answer (score 0):

You could take advance of HTML5 History API:
http://html5demos.com/history

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code**

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        alert(window.location.href);
     window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); // Updated answer Change URL ************ 
    alert(window.location.href);
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            _nav = jQuery('header');
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(5) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - _nav.height()
                }, 500);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

- You Can change URL using `window.location.hash='yourText'`

**Updated Answer:** for dynamic url change you can use `href`

`window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');`

Comment: I need it dynamically by getting which content is clicked

Comment: I also want the hash to appear before my content for instance it should be like `www.example.com/about` something like this

Comment: @Benjamin - And where is hash ('#') in your above comment 'www.example.com/about'  ??

Comment: thats my bad actually i dont need # on my address

Comment: moreover with your code iam getting `#undefined` in ma address bar

Comment: @Benjamin - use `window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');` it will resolve your `#undefined` issue